# Background image not showing full height

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I got this background image to be the right size when the page is normal, but when I add enough text that you have to start scrolling, the image doesn't cover the whole page. The image is taller than it shows, but when I change the height, the image just gets bigger, and I can't figure out how to show the rest of the image. Does any one know how to do this?

```
.bc-grnd-img {
    background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/little-cute-dumpy-frog-with-green-background-picture-id694848990?k=20&m=694848990&s=612x612&w=0&h=9tBJzT_Efz0GqI30Je72vvkqtSCQ5Deb_RRCdsG-e0c=");
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    height: 500px;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```
<div class="bc-grnd-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong in css
we don't use link for image, download image

```
.main{
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(to top, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%), url(1.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 109vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is very heavy and will lead to a slow website in the end, use Photoshop or Photopea to make sure your image is 1920px wide, it can be as tall as you like but remember the larger the image the slower the internet!

This code should then suit.....

```
background: url("img-name.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

50/50 should keep your image centered no matter how tall it is and for a static background we perhaps wouldn't want that repeating.

As a bonus, this also works good for Parallax backgrounds but the image should then definitely be taller than the display area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what I was looking for.  This is a link to a code pen https://codepen.io/Old-Gregg32/pen/gORVJbY?editors=1100 that should make it a bit clearer. I moved the text down so that you can see the problem. The image is tall enough to cover the page, but it won't stretch down.

Comment: Just use background-size:cover and if it doesn't end up tall enough you need a taller image.

Comment: I do have it on cover, but it still is not working. I don't need a taller image, because the image I have can cover the whole page, it just wont show the rest of the image. This is the image I used. https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/little-cute-dumpy-frog-with-green-background-picture-id694848990?k=20&m=694848990&s=612x612&w=0&h=9tBJzT_Efz0GqI30Je72vvkqtSCQ5Deb_RRCdsG-e0c= Do you see what I mean? It's tall enough, it just won't show the rest of it, and if I increase the height then it jut gets bigger.